# Simple assembly level program returns wrong value

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

```
section .data

section .bss
x1: resb    4
x2: resb    4
k:  resb    4
n:  resb    4

section .text

global _fibonacci

_fibonacci:
mov [n],    rdi
mov rax,    0
mov [x1],   rax

mov rax,    1
mov [x2],   rax

mov rax,    0
mov [k],    rax

mov rax, [n]
ret
```

This is a piece of my little function. I don't geht, why the returned value is '0', although the linked C-program gives a '10'. Does anybody know, what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your variables are declared to fit 4 bytes, but you're reading and writing 64-bit registers (8 bytes) from/to them.

This code:

```
mov rax,    0
mov [k],    rax
```

Will store 0 in the 8 bytes starting at `k`, i.e. both `k` and `n`.